# jquery lose scrolling ability after remove div

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I created a script to append a lightbox in jquery then to remove it on click.

I observed a strange behaviour on google chrome only.
If I scroll with mouse wheel when the lightbox is closing then, after I can't scroll my main div(I scroll a div for my website, not the body). I need to click on my div to scroll it again.
If I don't touch my mouse wheel when the lightbox is closing then everything works fine after, I can scroll my div normally....
I also observe this behaviour for a preloader div. 
Finally this bug always appears when I remove a div (while scrolling) with a z-index bigger than the main scrollable div...

css of my scrollable div and lightbox:

```
#inner-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 4;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.light-box-container {
    position: fixed;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

script to close the lightbox:

```
$(document).on('click touchend', function(e) {
    var $this = e.target;
    if ( $this.className == 'light-box-container light-box-anim' || $this.className == 'light-box-inner light-box-inner-anim' || $this.className == 'icon-remove') {
        $(lightboxImage).removeClass(lightboxAnimIn);
        $(lightboxInner).removeClass(lightboxAnimIn);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(lightboxContainer).removeClass(lightboxAnim);
        }, 300);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(lightboxContainer).remove();
            lightboxId++;
        }, 700);
    }
})
```

I don't know if it's a google chrome bug, or if it's due to my script.
And I really don't know how to solve it.
I tryed to trigger click or focus on my scrollable div but it don't works.

Comment: give me fiddle of this

Comment: maybe need to set overflow none while lightbox open...create a demo

Comment: fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4XXxH/9/ but it works in this fiddle...

Comment: I found the problem. it comes from a smooth scrolling plugin...